# Laravel javascript pagination, print, submit in view

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm making quiz website. User will choose questions from topics. And I will show questions to user in **create.blade.php**. The problem is if user pick 2 questions its not problem to show questions. If user pick 20 questions how to print them into view by 10 by 10. If user pick 50 questions how to print them into 10 by 10. I already used them like 5 `<div>`s. But it works but have to change this into 1 `<div>`.

1. splice
2. chunk
3. slice

**This is my view create.blade.php**

```
<form method="post" name="myform" action="{{ route('exams.store') }}">
{{ csrf_field() }}

<div id="account_details">
<div class="panel panel-default">
@if(count($questions) > 0)
    <div class="panel-body">
    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    @foreach($questions as $question)
        @if ($i > 1) <hr /> @endif
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Асуулт {{ $question->id }}.<br/><br/>{!! nl2br($question->question_text) !!}</strong><br/>
                    <input
                        type="hidden"
                        name="questions[{{ $question->id }}]"
                        value="{{ $question->id }}">
                @foreach($question->options as $option)
                    <br>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input
                            type="radio"
                            name="answers[{{ $question->id }}]"
                            value="{{ $option->id }}">
                        {{ $option->option }}
                    </label>
                @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
</div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="torol" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="all" value="{{ $questions->count() }}">

<div class="form-group">
<button type="submit">Дуусгах</button>
</div>

</form>
```

**ExamsController@create**

```
dd($questions);
```

**That's my questions**

```
Collection {#396 ▼
#items: array:19 [▼
0 => Question {#517 ▶}
1 => Question {#518 ▶}
2 => Question {#519 ▶}
3 => Question {#569 ▶}
4 => Question {#570 ▶}
5 => Question {#571 ▶}
6 => Question {#572 ▶}
7 => Question {#573 ▶}
8 => Question {#574 ▶}
9 => Question {#620 ▶}
10 => Question {#621 ▶}
11 => Question {#622 ▶}
12 => Question {#623 ▶}
13 => Question {#624 ▶}
14 => Question {#625 ▶}
15 => Question {#669 ▶}
16 => Question {#670 ▶}
17 => Question {#671 ▶}
18 => Question {#672 ▶}
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Controller**

```
$collections = $questions->split(5);
$collections->toArray();
```

**Create View**

```
@foreach ($collections[0] as $question)
...
@endforeach

@foreach ($collections[1] as $question)
...
@endforeach
```